# spring-cloud-stream-schema client; how to easily set up server port?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Everythhing is in the title, I think. spring-cloud-stream-schema-server port and spring-cloud-stream-schema client enpoint are hard coded.
See DefaultSchemaRegistryClient

```
public class DefaultSchemaRegistryClient implements SchemaRegistryClient {
...
    private String endpoint = "http://localhost:8990";
```

I also notices that SchemaRegistryClientConfiguration isn't protected by a Conditional annotation, that would be nice to allow a smooth replacement in the application context.

Is it planned that at least the client endpoitn can be customized?? I'm using Spring Boot to deploy the server and have the habit of being free to set a port, or at least use a services registry.

Thanks

Comment: Ok, sorry... the undocummented property is : spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint

Comment: Thanks for highlighting. This will be taken care soon: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/788

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if on the registry server.port=9090
use spring.cloud.stream.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint=localhost:9090 on client